# Conversion from Cartesian to Parametric function for a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am given a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Cartesian equation
$$
-5 x_1 - 2 x_2 + 2 x_3 = -15
$$
and I would like to find parametric equations
$$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}_0 + t_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + t_2 \mathbf{v}_2
$$
for it with
$
\mathbf{v}_1 =
\left( \begin{smallmatrix}
2 \\
-5 \\
0
\end{smallmatrix} \right)
$.

I can get any value I want when the vector $\mathbf{v}_1$ does not exists. However in this case vector $\mathbf{v}_1$ exists, so how do I find suitable vectors $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$?

Comment: Please have a look at our [basic guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math here. Also, your question is unclear: are you trying to derive a parametric equation for a plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$ from its Cartesian equation?

Comment: Hi @A.P. I will fix the maths equation. Yes, I am trying to derive the parametric equation for a plane from jts cartesian equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if a plane $\pi$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ has Cartesian equation
$$
a x_1 + b x_2 + c x_3 = d
$$
then the vector
$
\mathbf{n} = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$
is orthogonal to $\pi$. Also, recall that a parametric equation for $\pi$ has form
$$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}_0 + t_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + t_2 \mathbf{v}_2
$$
where $\mathbf{x}_0$ is the vector of coordinates of any point on $\pi$ and $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2$ are any two linearly independent vectors *orhtogonal* to $\mathbf{n}$.

Since you are already given $\mathbf{v}_1$ all you have to do is solve the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{cases}
0 = \mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 = a v_1^{(2)} + b v_2^{(2)} + c v_2^{(3)} \\
0 = \mathbf{v}_1 \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 = v_1^{(1)} v_1^{(2)} + v_2^{(1)} v_2^{(2)} + v_3^{(1)} v_3^{(2)} \\
d = \mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{x}_0 = a x_1^{(0)} + b x_2^{(0)} + c x_3^{(0)}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Note that here I'm looking for a vector $\mathbf{v}_2$ which is orthogonal to both $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{v}_1$. The first condition is necessary, while the second is for convenience (i.e. the equations are easy to write).

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations of the plane :
$$a x + b y + c z = d$$
is :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x & = & r \\
y & = & s \\
z & = & \dfrac{d}{c} - \dfrac{a}{c} r - \dfrac{b}{c} s
\end{array}\right.$$
Note : If $c = 0$ take ($x$ and $z$) or ($y$ and $z$) as parameters $z$.